# Powershell do not show string in print() when input() is used in the code

Tags: python-3.x, powershell

When I am trying to run same piece of code on CMD, it works but not on powershell.
I do not understand what could be the issue.

```
print("How old are you?", end = ' ')
age = input()
print("How tall are you?", end = ' ')
height = input()
print("How much do you weigh?", end = ' ')
weight = input()

print(f"So, you're {age} old, {height} tall and {weight} heavy.")
```

[image: Running code using CMD]

[image: Running code using Powershell]

The script does not print the first statement as well. It just gets stuck.
Any idea what could be wrong here?

This is what I got by running `Get-Command py`. It points to `py.exe`, as expected.
[image: get-command py]

The paths for py command from CMD and PS is same.
[image: py command path from PS]
[image: py command path from CMD]

Comment: Well, this is all I have. I tried to run the same program on the same version of python on different win10 system. It ran!! But since it should work line by line. I am not sure why print() is not getting executed. Addition to that the same program works from CMD, so that leaves me more confused.

Comment: Yes, under normal circumstances the script should behave the same, whether called from `cmd` or PowerShell. Unless you narrow the problem down further by yourself and provide additional information, we won't be able to help.

Answer (score -1):

try the following when your in the proper directory:

```
py .\ex11.py
```

Comment: @Brandon, the need to use a path rather than a mere file name only applies to invoking _executables themselves_, not to passing _arguments_ to executables (whose interpretation is up to the target executable, not PowerShell).